# Getting a part of number

Tags: c++, numbers

I have a number of type double. I want to get a part of it. For example,

If the number is **13041004236.980835** I want my program to remove first 4 digits and return **1004236.980835**

What is the shortest way to do this in c++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it with math:

```
auto digits = floor(log10(number)) + 1;
number = fmod(number, pow(10, digits - 4));
```

You can use the string stream approach from the other answer as well, but you need to use

```
ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
```

To not lose precision (assuming  you're using a double).

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << number;
std::string str = ss.str();

str.erase( 0, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a string, shorten it and convert it back.